# Why are there no arrays of objects in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, memory, types, typed-arrays

The Python module [array](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html) supports arrays, which are, unlike lists, stored in a contiguous manner, giving performance characteristics which are often more desirable. But the types of elements are limited to those listed in the documentation.

I can see why the types have to be ones with constant (or at least bounded from above) representation size. But don't pointers fall into that category? (The main implementation is written in C which, admittedly, allows pointers to different types to have different sizes, but they're all (perhaps except pointers to C functions, but that's not an issue for this question) convertible to `intptr_t`.) So, given boxing, arrays of arbitrary Python objects could be easily implemented, right? So why aren't they?

Comment: Would that be different from a `set` in python?

Comment: Python built-in lists are already implemented as arrays of pointers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

because we have lists, which are **exactly** an array of pointers.

python's `array` module stores data **contiguously**, python objects have dynamic sizes and cannot be stored contiguously, so we have lists which store the pointers.

the main use of `array` is for passing around C-style arrays between different C functions, arrays are slower than lists for numeric types due to the boxing and unboxing, so it has no use in any pure python code.

Comment: By "arrays are slower than lists for numeric types due to the boxing and unboxing" do you mean that Python arrays don't store e.g. `int`s directly but rather pointers to `int`s, Python lists however do? I thought it was the other way around.

Comment: @ByteEater python can't deal with C-style ints, it first has to Box them into "python int object", and any access to the array will create a new "python int object", lists just store pointers to the already-created "python int object", so its access is cheaper, same thing on writes.